# W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease Connection failed [IP: 65.52.183.205 80]

Tags: apt, updates

I am using ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS version in my laptop it seems every things working perfectly fine but i when i run sudo apt update in my terminal i get

```
W:Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 65.52.183.205 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.e here
```

Comment: Wait an hour or two. Try again later, and see if the issue still happens. The repo might have just gone down for a bit for some reason.

Comment: Check if you local time and the timezone is correct